# c# .net mvc: jquery json result from actionResult method returns default page html

Tags: c#, jquery, json

VS 2015

I have some minor jQuery that does a `POST` to an `ActionResult` method.  The method should return a Json object; empty on success or with elements if there is an error.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(string thing, string thing_1, string thing_2) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            if (e.Message.Trim().Equals("Not Authorized")) {
                Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            } else {
                Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed;
            }
            Response.StatusDescription = e.Message.Trim();

            Debug.WriteLine("MyMethod failed: " + e.Message);

            return Json(new {error = e.Message});
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("MyMethod END ");

        Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;

        return Json(new {});
    }
```

When run in VS debug mode I see the "MyMethod failed: " message in the `catch` block.

When the response gets back to jQuery things are very strange.  In Chrome's Developer Tools / Sources screen I can break in the jQuery `.fail` block.

```
    .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.dir(jqXhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
```

`textStatus` = "parsererror"

`errorThrown` =

```
message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:50074/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:8724:19)
    at done (http://localhost:50074/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:9192:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:50074/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:9484:9)"
```

`jqXhr` on the other hand holds a 200 level status code, its status Text = OK but the `responseText` does not contain my json response.  It contains the entire content of the default project home page.  That starts with "" and so confuses json.

What am I missing?

Comment: What page is normally returned when an error occurs? e.g. Do you have custom errors set to return your homepage?

Comment: I think this line of code is your problem here `Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;`. As you return an unauthorized status code, it will redirect you to your default or login page (can't remember which one).

Comment: Just for the try, change Unauthorized to Forbidden.

Comment: No custom errors. A different post talked about setting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` for that purpose.  Also, changing Unauthorized to Forbidden changes nothing.  I've tried a few other status codes as well since your notes and the same thing happens.